# add Target doesn't work ? ios

Tags: ios, ios8, uibutton, ios9

I have two viewControllers:

1. viewController1, it's view bounds is fullScreen.
2. viewController2, it's view bounds doesn't fill the fullScreen

I need to show the viewController2 above viewController1, but i need to set the `viewController2.view = UIColor.clearColor()` to make viewController2 visible.

so i can't use `self.navigationController?.pushViewController` because the navigationController hide viewController1.views when the viewController2 is pushed !

actually i don't know why , and i don't know How to prevent that ?

so I found this solution, instead of using the pushViewController I will use this: `viewController1.view.addSubview(viewController2.view)`

but now the addTarget for the buttons in viewController2 stop calling the selector. why ?

Comment: Are you retaining view controller 2?

Comment: @Wain oh, yes that's that's correct, thanks, but Could you please tell me why the navigationController hide the previous controllers ?

Comment: It's how it works, it shows one at a time. You should add a child view controller